# how to write a test method for following apex code

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

how to write a test method for following apex code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
      You belong to the {!account.name} account.<p/>
      Account Name: 
      <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
      <p/>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!save}"
                          value="Save New Account Name"/>
     </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to salesforce.stackoverflow. If you expect an answer from the community, we expect you to put a bit more effort in your questions. Please elaborate in what context your code is running and what you have already done or found by yourself to test it. That way we can answer with a most appropriate specificness :)

Answer (score 4):

What you have posted is in fact [Visualforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce), which does not require test code. When you use a [custom or extention controler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller.htm), you would be combining Visualforce with [Apex](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex), and would require test code for the custom or extention controller.

Visualforce with standartcontrollers can already offer quite some functionality, but there's no native way to write tests for this, if you want to test the front end behavior other tools can be used such as selenium (i believe).